# Ajax Push written in C/C++?

Tags: c++, ajax, linux, html, ape

I have existing chat server code written in C/C++ that communicates over TCP/IP with client installed GUI.  I'd like to also allow "web" access to this functionality, where users can simply go to my website, have it display a nice basic HTML5 driven GUI, and have them interact with my chat server code and other users.

So: backend written in C, frontend HTML5 website that updates to clients immediately via Ajax Push.  Is there some kind of C library I can use to achieve this?  I would also accept a solution using technology that isn't Ajax Push as long as it functions how I describe.  Note that I want to extend to be more data/traffic than simple chat, so I want this as close to realtime as possible.

I understand that APE (server) allows you to do stuff *like* this, but you have to write your backend in javascript?  Is there a way to easily 'glue' it to a C/C++ server via pipes or something?

I'm working in Linux..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question, but this sounds like what you're looking for: http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt